# Instantiate Swift View Controller in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I created a view controller in Swift and now I want to instantiate that view controller in an Objective-C file.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

The problem I'm having is that Xcode doesn't recognize **DetailViewController** as a class. Is this something that I need to declare in the header file? I was hoping it was as easy as:

```
#import "DetailViewController.swift"
```

but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer for working with swift file and objective-c files here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

This provides examples / instructions for working both ways. The situation you're looking for is about half way down the page.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, I was able to get it to work by using `#import <ProductModuleName-Swift.h>` while `#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

> To import Swift code into Objective-C from the same framework
>
> Under Build Settings, in Packaging, make sure the Defines Module
>   setting for that framework target is set to “Yes". Import the Swift
>   code from that framework target into any Objective-C .m file within
>   that framework target using this syntax and substituting the
>   appropriate names:

```
#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
```